# git -- handling frozen content

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, ignore

Almost all projects that I've worked on have some kind of "frozen content" that should always come when cloned, yet rarely be changed (see below for an example). I've tried different approaches using git, but they're all error-prone: people frequently wind up accidentally committing changes.

It's a subtle case to be sure: the files/folders *must* be versioned, but the *vast* majority of changes shouldn't get pushed.

Looking around I have a couple options:

- `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`:  **Problem** -- this [would appear to be a local setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818305/git-assume-unchanged-implications), so this only solves the problem on a given machine.  New clones are prone to forget and still commit changes by accident.
- `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>`: **Problem** -- Appears to have the same issue, since I don't *think* changes to the index are ever propogated.
- `git rm --cached <file>`: **Problem** -- not really a solution at all since this toasts everyone's copy when pushed!
- `echo <file> >> .gitignore`: **Problem** -- not really a solution, since this only controls whether an object is *added* to the repo.
- use a smudge/clean filter to exclude file changes from commits (see jthill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528104/how-to-freeze-a-file-in-a-repository)): **Problem** -- complicated, error prone: still needs each developper to locally config.

**An acceptable answer to this question doesn't require special actions by each new developer**.

Why?  Because this is precisely the problem with the above solutions, which, in my experience leads to situations where "somebody has committed that file again".

Searches easily turn up many questions.  We need a final answer!

- [How to freeze a file in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528104/how-to-freeze-a-file-in-a-repository)
- [Prevent local changes getting pushed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173726/prevent-local-changes-getting-pushed-in-git)
- [git assume-unchanged implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818305/git-assume-unchanged-implications)
- [Howto prevent git from pushing changes to some files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007397/howto-prevent-git-from-pushing-changes-to-some-files)
- [Ignore modified (but not committed) files in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git)
- [Preventing a file overwrite with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321561/preventing-a-file-overwrite-with-git)

Example:

Here's the case I'm dealing with ATM.  My project is a website that embeds wiki software (which I did not write). The wiki component needs a non-trivial folder structure which is used rather like a database (should probably be one).  It needs to find the folders and files already there to work.  After awhile these files get big -- we don't want to track those changes!  This folder structure also contains some config (I know).  If I could include the bare copy in the repo, and somehow (almost) never track its changes, that would be perfect.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what the "frozen content" might be? Are you talking about configuration files? Database fixtures? Something else?

Comment: Great question (and good research effort). This really is a Git FAQ, and deserves a canonical answer.

Comment: @Chris -- added some description of the folders / files.

Comment: We have the same requirement: We use Flyway to manage database changes. Once a Flyway script has been applied to a production database, it is criticial that not a single bit is ever changed again in that file (otherwise Flyway will be confused with future deployments because the checksum for the SQL script has changed). Still it has to remain in the repository and be deployed with the application in future releases. With all the features GIt has, I would have expected a simple feature to centrally "seal" a file against future updates. (Of course the seal should be removable, just in case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear what types of files you're talking about.

In the case of configuration files, I always recommend the following approach:

1. Commit a sample configuration file with sane defaults, e.g. `config.sample.ini`.
2. Ignore the non-sample file, e.g. `config.ini`.
3. As part of the "start up" procedure on new machines, the `config.sample.ini` file must be copied to `config.ini` and and customised. Document this process in your README, or wiki, or wherever.
4. Make sure your code "fails properly" if the config file is missing, e.g. when the software starts it will immediately error out with "Could not find config.ini. Did you copy the sample file?"

This ensures that the sample file can be easily updated. It ensures that the configuration file is not committed. It fails quickly if it's done wrong. And it's relatively simple to implement.

The quickest way to get from a committed `config.ini` to an ignored `config.ini` and a committed `config.sample.ini` is likely to do something like

```
git mv config.ini config.sample.ini
echo config.ini >> .gitignore
git commit -a -m "Replace config file with sample config file"
```

**Update:**

Your wiki example is an interesting one.

You're right that a deep tree of `.sample` files would be difficult to manage, but you can get the same effect with a zip file or tarball:

1. Create an archive that will be committed to the repository containing your base wiki content, e.g. `wiki.zip`.
2. Ignore the directory where the wiki will be extracted, e.g. `path/to/wiki-root`.
3. Add "extract wiki with `unzip -d path/to/wiki-root`" to your documentation. This is now part of your install / deploy procedure.

Now you can update the zip file as necessary and commit those changes, while ignoring changes to the extracted files.

Comment: Yes, that's how I have always see it done, too. The OP's problem really is that one file is serving two roles: configuration template, and configuration file. Having separate files is the cleanest solution.

Comment: I do like that approach.  Check out the example I added to the bottom of my question (this is what I'm actually facing).  Perhaps I could duplicate the whole folder structure as a template, but that seems excessive.

Comment: @Cris I like this answer.  This will solve the problem for my usecase.  I've had an idea about a solution using *client-side* hooks, that I want to test.  If it works, I want to put it up as an alternate solution to see what people think, hopefully later today.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the only way to enforce a "don't change this" policy without voluntary action in each clone of the repo is to install a [server-side hook](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks) for them. A pre-receive hook can inspect the incoming commits for changes to a frozen file and reject them (unless the commit message matches some magic pattern that makes it pass).

Server-side hooks only work when you control the central repo, i.e. it can't be on GitHub or some such service.

Comment: Ah, a close miss.  It's too bad we can't use that for github. Still, this will help many.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following file in your project as `<proj-root>/.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh

numFilesToVerify=0
IFS=$'\n'

for l in `git diff --name-only --cached`; do 
    while read m; do
        [[ $l == $m ]] && verify="$verify"`echo " * $l"`$'\n' && ((numFilesToVerify++))
    done < .gitverify
done 

if [ $numFilesToVerify -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "\nYou're changing $numFilesToVerify frozen files:";
    echo "$verify"
    read -p "Do you know what you're doing? (yes/no): " reply < /dev/tty
    if [ "$reply" != "yes" ]; then
        echo 'commit aborted.'
        exit 1;
    fi
fi

unset IFS
```

Then list the files or directories you want to freeze in the file `<proj-root>/.gitverify`.  Use the * wildcard if you want:

```
testdir/test*
```

Here's what happens if I try to commit changes to the files `tesdir/test` and `testdir/test2`

```
$ git commit -m 'test'
You're changing 2 frozen files:
 * testdir/test
 * testdir/test2

Do you know what you're doing? (yes/no): no
commit aborted.
```

Advantages:

- I can easily add / remove files from the freeze list
- If updating part of a tar (see Chris's answer) one is prone to overwrite a part not intended to be changed.  No tars needed here, and it tells you what potentially dumb thing you're doing.
- doesn't use server side hooks so no issues with access or having multiple remotes.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but doesn't it violate your "An acceptable answer to this question doesn't require special actions by each new developer" requirement? I'm fairly certain that each user will have to set this hook manually after cloning, as hooks are not part of the repository.

Comment: @Chris darn!  I assumed they were.